# Найти по первым 4 символам и удалить строку в файле

Tags: java

Задание: удалить товар из базы по серийному номеру(4 цифры). Вопрос: как прочитать только первые 4 символа в каждой строке и если эти символы совпадают, то удалить строку? У меня программа ищет строку целиком и удаляет ее:

```
package org.FinalProgram;
import java.io.*;

public class SearchDel {
    public int number;

    public SearchDel(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }

    //getters
    public int getNumber(){
        return number;
    }

    //setters
    public void setNumber(int number){
        this.number=number;
    }

    public void delete() throws IOException{
        File inputFile = new File("C:\\data\\data.txt");
        File tempFile = new File("C:\\data\\myTempFile.txt");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

        String lineToRemove = "Строка";
        String currentLine;

        while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
            String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
            if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
            writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        writer.close(); 
        reader.close(); 
        boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

[Java String.startsWith() tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_startswith.htm)

Как я понимаю, вам стоит использовать метод startsWith, вместо equals.

startsWith(String prefix) - проверяет, начинается ли строка с указанного префикса;
startsWith(String prefix, int toffset) - проверяет, начинается ли строка в указанной позиции с указанного префикса;

Comment: А префиксом может быть int или только String?

Comment: @PoGostu только String. Можете писать так `startsWith(String.valueOf(int));`

Comment: Все получилось) Только почему то старый файл не удаляет и новый не переименовывает?

Comment: @PoGostu попробуйте что-то из этого http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/rename-a-file-using-java

Comment: так у меня есть строчка boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile); только ничего не происходит